# Changes of electric potential energy in a split liquid drop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

A liquid drop with radius $R$, with a uniform charge $Q$, divides in two, with equal radius and charges, that move away until they are very far from each other. What is the variation of electric potential energy?

Answer is probably $\Delta U = (1−2^{2/3}) \left[\frac{(3Q^2/5)}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R}\right]$.

I tried considering the volume of each new drop to be half of the big drop's, giving me a radius of $R*2^{-1/3}$. After that, I considered both drops to be particles and used the formula $U = \frac{Q_1Q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}$, with $r$ being the distance between the particles, leaving me with $\Delta U = \left[\frac{(Q^2/4)}{4\pi\epsilon_0 2^{2/3}R}\right]$.

Comment: The potential at what point? at he surface of one of the drops?

Comment: @trula The energy of the system, I assume. Potential and potential energy are two different concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Here, the question says that the drops are moved infinitely far. This is to ignore the energy of interaction between the two spheres. ie: Ignore $\frac{Q_1Q_2}{4\pi \varepsilon_0 r} $

Also, the probable answer seems incorrect since $2^{2/3}>1$ and energy is only lost when charges redistribute.

Now,

- when the drop splits, the Radius changes as:
  $R_{final} = R_f = R\left(2^{-1/3}\right)$   which can be found from volume being halved.
- The charge, as given changes as $Q_{final} =Q_f=\frac{Q}{2}$.
- When the drop had $Q$ charge on it, There would be a potential over the drop $V$. We can find the energy stored as :

$E= \frac{Q^2}{2C}$

where $C$ is the capacitance of sphere : $C=4\pi \varepsilon R$

*Initial energy*

$E_i = 
\frac{Q^2}{8\pi \varepsilon R} $

*final energy*

$E'_f = \frac{\left(\frac{Q} {2} \right)^2}{8\pi \varepsilon \left(2^{-1/3}R\right) }$

Since there are two spheres, $E_f = 2\times E'_f$

$E_f = 2\times \frac{\left(\frac{Q} {2} \right)^2}{8\pi \varepsilon \left(2^{-1/3}R\right) } = \frac{Q^2}{8\pi \varepsilon R} \times 2^{-2/3} $

$E_i - E_f = \frac{Q^2}{8\pi \varepsilon R}\left(1-2^{-2/3}\right) $

Trying to bring to the expected answer gives :

$\Delta U =- \left(2^{2/3}-1\right)\frac{Q^2}{4\pi\varepsilon  2^{5/3}R} $

Which is similar. I think it is a typo or maybe the value of $\epsilon = \frac{5} {3} \varepsilon_0$